# Execute performExecute() using public static main(String args)

Tags: java, program-entry-point, public-method

```
 public class XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl extends ControllerCommandImpl implements XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmd {
    public final String CLASSNAME = this.getClass().getName();
    public void performExecute() throws ECException { /* code is here*/ }

    private void callUSInterface() throws ECException { /* code is here*/ }

    private void callDEInterface() throws ECException { /* code is here*/ }

    private void callUKInterface() throws ECException { /* code is here*/ }

    public void setRequestProperties(TypedProperty req) throws ECException { /* code is here*/ }

    private void displayResponse(StringBuffer testResult) { /* code is here*/ }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl PGDirTestController = new XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl();
        PGDirTestController.performExecute();
    }

}
```

I'm simply trying to run this application as a java application in Eclipse-RAD using `public static void main(String[] args)` but it is giving me an error of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type ECException
```

on:

```
PGDirTestController.performExecute();
```

Please go easy on me, I'm pretty new to Java still.

Comment: Did you see the dialog "Error exist in required project(s): Project-Name Proceed with launch? □ Always launch without asking [Proceed] [Cancel]" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you declared:

```
public void performExecute() throws ECException
```

Then you are forced to deal with `ECException`.

So when you call it, you should surround it with `try-catch` or declare the method in which you call it to `throw` the exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl PGDirTestController = new 
               XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl();
      try {
          PGDirTestController.performExecute();
      } catch(ECException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Handle the exception!
        }
}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ECException {
     XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl PGDirTestController = new 
              XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl();
     PGDirTestController.performExecute();
}
```

Comment: Watch out with `catch(ECException e) { }`. I understand this is only an example but you should show good practices. Exceptions are not something you should be afraid of ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 Indeed ;) This was only for example. I will edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

First, variables should start with lowercase as per [Java convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), otherwise it's confusing:

```
XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl pGDirTestController = new XGetProgramGuideDirectTestControllerCmdImpl();
```

About your question, *Unhandled exception type* means this method throws an exception that's not a RuntimeException and you're not handling it. In Java, you must explicitly catch all exceptions that are not children of RuntimeException.

```
try {
    pGDirTestController.performExecute();
} catch (final ECException e) {
    // Do whatever you need to do if this exception is thrown
}
```

The catch part will be executed whenever an `ECException` is thrown. You should add code here to handle what to do if this exception is thrown. I strongly advise you against leaving this catch empty, because if the exception is thrown, you'll never know.

I strongly suggest you get a Java book/tutorial if you will be working with Java. This is very basic stuff, so you better understand this very well. Good luck.